# What's an easy way to get started with an interactive Javascript slideshow / image viewer?

Tags: javascript, image

I'm very very new to Javascript.  What I'd like to do is one of those rows of smaller images, that when you click on one it pops up bigger with left and right arrows for sliding through the photos.

What's the easiest way to get started doing something like that?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It's called an image carousel - you can find tons of plug-ins. Both in Plain old javascript or jquery (for sure :)

Comment: Not necessarily a carousel, many JQuery image galleries reproduce that effect. :)

Comment: Are you trying to implement one your own or do you just want to use an existing one? That *makes difference*.

Comment: @Frankie, Not trying to implement one, but I'd like to find one that's easy to deploy and understand.  Thanks.

Comment: @Nupul - Thanks for the pointer, I searched carousels and it looks like the effect I'm looking for is actually lightbox.  But thanks again for the pointer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know we're not your research site, but since you're asking for the **easiest** way, I'd recommend [HighSlide JS](http://highslide.com). It doesn't require JQuery, is highly personalizable, comes with examples which you can just copypasta and a nice tutorial.

Of course, if you'd include the [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) lib to your page, you could also try one of [these fancier plugins](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/08/25-jquery-image-galleries-and-slideshow-plugins/). And there are also some JQuery [carousel](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/01/jquery-carousel.html) plugins as noted by @Nupul.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  After googling and unable to find anything by way of a *simple* examples or tutorial on this subject, I thought stackoverflow was a reasonable place to ask this question.  Where would you suggest I go for help, if not here?

Comment: No problem, it's ok to post here if you didn't find anything. :) I just commented about research as I think most people wouldn't reply for the same reason, guess you were searching for the wrong keywords maybe. Now that you talk about a *simple* tutorial/plugin, I guess you're right, they aren't very easy to find. :P

Comment: Hi again, yes it looks like I was searching for the wrong thing.  The effect I want is actually called 'lightbox'.  But the answers provided here sent me in the right direction!  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, colorbox (jquery) and highslide (non-jquery) are prime examples of lightboxes, no problem. :)

Comment: HighSlide JS is NOT open source licensed. You need to pay them for use on commercial or government sites and other uses.

Comment: OP did not include any specific usage, instead he asked for an easy implementation/tutorial to which I replied. But I understand your concern, HJ is just an example, there are many open source lightboxes for commercial use, if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [galleries plugins at Web Resource Depot](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/category/goodies/gallery/)